# Plotting a heatmap out of common value matrix in R

Tags: r, heatmap

I have a tab-separated file like the following:

```
        C1P C2P C3P C4P C5P
sam1    3 cp    3 cp    3 cp    3 cp    3 cp
sam2    S3c 4 cp    3 cp    3 cp    S3c
sam3    3 cp    3 cp    3 cp    3 cp    3 cp
sam4    3 cp    3 cp    LOH LOH 3 cp
sam5    3 cp    3 cp    3 cp    3 cp    3 cp
sam6    4 cp    4 cp    UPD UPD UPT
```

Now I want to assign a color to each value [condition]...and let the color appear wherever there is the same value, thereby making a heatmap that represents occurences of a specific condition [values in the column] in each sample [row headers].

[image]

Right now I am assigning numeric values to each condition, then generating the heatmap through pheatmap. But I was looking for more robust way of doing it.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's better to put some usable to copy and past in R to have good answers. However you can look at `geom_tile()` in `ggplot2` package, and, looking at your data, you'll have to put them from wide to long format before it.

Comment: Have you tried `image()`

Comment: @s_t Thank You...I shall keep that in mind... ya I saw ggplots is working wonders around the labs....

Comment: @HolgerBarlt I haven't tried..but I tried to work with it before but I found it difficult to wrap my head around that package... so I switched to pheatmap and heatmap2 ... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you fairly close:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    rownames_to_column("row") %>%
    gather(col, Value, -row) %>%
    mutate(
        row = factor(row, levels = rev(unique(row))),
        Value = factor(Value)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(col, row, fill = Value)) +
    geom_tile() +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c(
        `3 cp` = "yellow",
        `4 cp` = "red",
        LOH = "blue",
        S3c = "lightgreen",
        UPD = "darkgreen",
        UPT = "black")) +
    labs(x = "", y = "") +
    theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Explanation:

1. Reshape data from wide to long.
2. Use `geom_tile` to draw a heatmap, where the fill colour is given by the `factor` levels of your values.
3. The rest is aesthetic "fluff" to increase the similarity to the image you link to.

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "        C1P C2P C3P C4P C5P
sam1    '3 cp'    '3 cp'    '3 cp'    '3 cp'    '3 cp'
sam2    'S3c' '4 cp'    '3 cp'    '3 cp'    'S3c'
sam3    '3 cp'    '3 cp'    '3 cp'    '3 cp'    '3 cp'
sam4    '3 cp'    '3 cp'    LOH LOH '3 cp'
sam5    '3 cp'    '3 cp'    '3 cp'    '3 cp'    '3 cp'
sam6    '4 cp'    '4 cp'    UPD UPD UPT", header = T)
```

Comment: ...Thank you...thats exactly what I am looking for. Since I am not very affluent in R scripts :( , I have a few doubts:  Q1: what is `%>%` doing ?  Q2: mutate is a function that is converting the rows into a single column ? and I actually get a whole lot of conditions not just 4-5 of them, so how can i dynamically assign colors to them ?..............Thanks a lot for the help !

Comment: @SangramJB Q1. `%>%` is the `magrittr` pipe operator, that pipes the left hand side values into expressions on the right hand side (think `x %>% f()` instead of `f(x)`). Q2. `mutate` is one of the key `dplyr` functions to add/change variables in a `data.frame` or `tibble`. Generally, I'd recommend a basic `dplyr`/`ggplot2` tutorial to get started. I'd do a terrible job trying to explain the details here in a comment.

Comment: :D...No that would be ok...I can definitely go through some tutorials.... dplyr/ggplot2 ...got it ...Thanks a lot....just one more thing..what if I had 15 fields to assign colors to instead  of six as in example ??? how can I assign colors automatically ??

Comment: You're very welcome @SangramJB. If you remove the entire `scale_fill_manual(...)` block, `ggplot` will assign colours automatically. I only used `scale_fill_manual` to increase the aesthetic similarity with the plot you showed in your OP.